# React Native Animation app journey animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

I am trying to achieve user introduction animation like the video below, Can you please guide to how to achieve it in react native. [image]

Comment: I would say that this is likely a gif or short video, to animate this many items would be incredibly difficult (not impossible as there are CSS wizards out there...)   Unfortunately you must show what you have tried so far in order for others to help and the SO community will likely not be able to offer a "good" solution without you first showing what has been attempted or narrowing-down the question

Comment: I would guess that this is a video too but another library you can checkout is skia (https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use 2 libs for this:

First this one [react-native-reanimated-carousel](https://github.com/dohooo/react-native-reanimated-carousel) like this to achieve the carousel:

```js
       <ReanimatedCarousel
        data={dataPayload}
        enabled={swipeEnabled}
        height={height ?? dimensions.height}
        loop={loop}
        pagingEnabled
        panGestureHandlerProps={{
          activeOffsetX: [-10, 10],
        }}
        ref={ref}
        renderItem={renderFunction}
        snapEnabled
        width={width ?? dimensions.width}
        onProgressChange={(_, absoluteProgress) => {
          progress.value = absoluteProgress;
        }}
        onSnapToItem={onIndexChange}
      />
```

And then I would use a lottie.json and [lottie-react-native](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native) for the animation. Read more about [lottie here](https://lottiefiles.com/).

Then depending on the current active index of the carousel I would play the animation forward/backward.